# iOS Rich Notification and async request - RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, rx-swift

I have to update the notification send by Batch. I have to :

1. Take the content of the notification received by Batch
2. Send it to the back end
3. Receive the content updated
4. Show notification.

My problem is : when I send it to the back end, the function didReceive complete and the notification is send before the update.

How can I wait for the response of the back end? 
Or have you an other idea?

```
import BatchExtension
import Core
import Middleware
import RxSwift

class NotificationService: BAENotificationServiceExtension {
var alreadySend: Bool = false

let batchHelper = BAERichNotificationHelper()

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = request.content.userInfo

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let defaultMessage = userInfo["on_error"] as? String {
        let body = request.content.body
        if body.contains("$") {
            if let image = userInfo["image"] as? String {
                renderPush(title: request.content.title, body: body, image: image, defaultMessage: defaultMessage)
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.didReceive(request, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
        return
    }
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

private func renderPush(title: String, body: String, image: String?, defaultMessage: String) {
    let customPushNotification = CustomPushNotificationContent(body: body, image: image)

    let credentialsStore = DummyCredentialStore()
    let serviceProvider = ServiceProvider(
        networkProvider: NetworkProvider(
            endPoint: Server.endPoint,
            timeoutIntervalForResource: 10,
            timeoutIntervalForRequest: 10
        ),
        credentialsStore: credentialsStore
    )

    if let credentials = DummyCredentialStore.getCredentialsFromSharedContainer() {
        let service = serviceProvider.getPushNotificationService(credentials: credentials)

        _ = service.renderPush(pushNotificationContent: customPushNotification)
            .subscribe(onNext: { result in
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = title

                if result.result != "ok" {
                    content.body = defaultMessage
                } else {
                    content.body = result.body
                }
                if result.image != nil {
                    if let urlImage = URL(string: result.image ?? "") {
                        do {
                            let attachement = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "image", url: urlImage, options: nil)
                            content.attachments.append(attachement)
                        } catch {}
                    }
                }

               self.bestAttemptContent = content
            })
    }
}
```

}